# Discrete Mathematics Element Proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Let $a,b\in\Bbb R$ with $a<b$. Consider the following (interval) subsets of $\Bbb R$: $(a,b):=\{x\mid (a<x)\land(x<b)\}$, $(-\infty,a]:=\{x\mid (x\le a)\}$, and $[b,\infty):=\{x\mid (x\ge b\}$. Prove using element proof that $\overline{(a,b)}=(-\infty,a]\cup[b,\infty)$.

Sorry for asking such a general question, but I really don't know how to start this question.

Comment: Because topology tells me that $\bar{A}$ means the closure of $A$, I'll write $A^C$ instead. Anyway. Suppose $x \in (a, b)^C$. Then what?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm really not sure what that means.

Comment: By your conventions, to say $x \in \bar{A}$ is to say that $x \not\in A$. I was referencing other notation you may see. Well, if $x \not\in (a, b)$, what can we say about $x$?

Comment: If (a,b) are elements of the real numbers, and x is not on element of (a,b) Then x is not a real number.

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: What you are saying doesn't make sense, @Jordan.

Answer (score 0):

**Proof.** Suppose $x \in \overline{(a, b)}$. Then $x \not\in (a, b)$, that is, it is not the case that $x < b$ and $x > a$. So, either $x \geq b$ or $x \leq a$. The result follows. The reverse inclusion can be proved similarly. $\square$

Okay, line by line.

> Suppose $x \in \overline{(a, b)}$.

This is what we assume.

> Then $x \not\in (a, b)$, ...

This is simply the definition of set complement.

> ...that is, it is not the case that $x < b$ and $x > a$.

We're using the definition of what $(a, b)$ means. We are now getting ready to use de Morgan's laws.

> So, either $x \geq b$ or $x \leq a$.

This is where we use de Morgan's laws.

I suggest you reread your notes and seek out other similar exercises to get a handle for these kinds of questions.

Comment: Thank you for solving this for me. At the start, how do you know that you need to assume that x is not an element of (a, b)?

Comment: It's the definition of the notation $x \in \overline{(a, b)}$ in this convention.

Comment: Oh, when I read the question I didn't even see the compliment. Thank you so much. Guess I need to look at the questions closer.